# In any scenario in automation where implicit wait will fail every time but explicit wait will pass even both having 10 sec default Time?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriverwait, automation-testing

In any scenario in automation where implicit wait will fail every time but explicit wait will pass even both having 10 sec default Time ? Its not as depend upon condition e.g clickable point of view.

Researched and brainstorming on the question but not find exact answer which i can co-relate

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: An implicit wait may fail to wait until the proper condition is reached, but you won't ever see implicit throw a timeout while explicit does not.  They both ignore no such element exceptions, but explicit waits can wait for a condition to be met beyond just existence in the DOM.  You should never mix them, as that will lead to competing polling loops and produce unpredictable results.